# Error configuring ACME ssl for ejabberd

Tags: ssl, html, ejabberd, xmpp

I would like to know if there is a way to add a sucure ssl certifacte to ejabberd?

Someone reccomeneded ACME, but I run into an error:

```
root@uosib:~ ejabberdctl request-certificate all
Error: error
Error: "HTTP error: unexpected content type: text/html"
root@uosib:~ ejabberdctl request-certificate    uosib.ehvengate.com,pubsub.uosib.ehvengate.com,conference.uosib.ehvengate.com,
Error: error
Error: "HTTP error: unexpected content type: text/html"
root@uosib:~
```

Please help me figure this out.... Thanks!